# Magento 2: change the design of minicart and cart popup

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, mini-cart

I am having png image. It should be act us mini-cart and i need to change the design of cart popup.

I don't know the paths for that.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2  manage the **minicart using**

- knockout Js which is using HTML template and localstorege.
- Localstorege manage via [`Private content`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)

Minicart related HTML and Js file:

**HTML files located at**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart

**JS file/folder which is doing  knock js operator**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/configure

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js

**PHTML File**
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

Before, working on minicart, you have to understand who Knockout js working  and

How Private content of specific to individual users is managed and used at local storage as private content storeage at the web browser.

Comment: I am having cart as a .png image ..how can i replace with existing cart

Comment: SUBBULAKSHMI G, you have start yourself, then i will help if you will get any issue. You have asking support like : i have a requirement and i want to implement it.This type of requirement  need long and brief and cannot possible on MSE

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the following file paths to get the structure of minicart.

```
app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phmtl

app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/*
```

Comment: i have added my html design in the minicart.phtml ,..it is not reflecting

Comment: remove generated, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed and check again.

Comment: I am having cart as a .png image ..how can i replace with existing cart

Answer (score -1):

You can try below extension to solved your problem:

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageplaza-module-quick-cart.html

Thanks